# How To merge 2 object and calculate its final data in php?

Tags: php, dictionary

I have many objects inside php array as shown in example.  I want to get new similar object which contains all the unique properties from all the objects, if same property is found then the value of amount inside that property of and object will be added.

For example:

```
$data = array({"Browser": {
    "Chrome": {
        "amount": 1721
    },
    "Firefox": {
        "amount": 121
    }
  },
 "City": {
    "USA": {
        "amount": 2220
    },
    "China": {
        "amount": 121
    }
  },
 },
 {"Browser": {
    "UC Browser": {
        "amount": 117
    },
    "Chrome": {
        "amount": 40
    }
 },
 "City": {
    "USA": {
        "amount": 212
    },
    "UK": {
        "amount": 21
    }
   },
 });
```

Output that I am trying to get:

```
{
  "Browser": {
    "UC Browser": {
        "amount": 117
    },
    "Chrome": {
        "amount": 1761 //<=40 + 1721 
    },
    "Firefox": {
        "amount": 121
    }
 },
 "City": {
    "USA": {
        "amount": 2432 //<= 1721 + 212
    },
    "UK": {
        "amount": 21
    },
    "China": {
        "amount": 121
    }
  },
}
```

Similarly there will be about 30 similar object inside array with same structure.
I tried more than a week, But I could not solve this problem.

Comment: How you are making first object ?

Comment: Down voting because you have not included your try, please add your try?

Comment: It's just a sample.

Comment: Please add your try ?

Comment: Actually I have broken down by problem into small pieces , Because I Can't show every thing here and I am getting data from database.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by creating a recursion function that will sum `amount` elements for the same keys, something like that:

```
function amount_sum_recursive(...$arrays) {
    $result = [];
    // iterate through $arrays as it can be more than 2 root elements in the $data array 
    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                // if the $value is an array - we need to go deeper 
                $result[$key] = amount_sum_recursive($result[$key] ?? [], $value);
            } else {
                // the $value is not an array - it's `amount` key:
                // simply add current $value to the existing one in the $result array
                $result[$key] += $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Test:

```
$result = amount_sum_recursive(...$data);
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
{
    "Browser": {
        "Chrome": {
            "amount": 1761
        },
        "Firefox": {
            "amount": 121
        },
        "UC Browser": {
            "amount": 117
        }
    },
    "City": {
        "USA": {
            "amount": 2432
        },
        "China": {
            "amount": 121
        },
        "UK": {
            "amount": 21
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a side note: as you @mina-pandey mentioned, that you're getting $data from the database, it will be much easier (and much more efficient) to optimize your DB query to get aggregated values, rather then recursively traverse arrays in PHP

Comment: what are you doing here **$result[$key] = amount_sum_recursive($result[$key] ?? [], $value);**

Comment: It's called recursion - I'm calling `amount_sum_recursive` from itself. You can read more about recursion here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/
Basically, what we need to do at this line is to recursively merge array inside `$result[$key]` with array `$value`. To do so, we need to pass `$result[$key]` (or an empty array if `$result[$key]` is not set yet) and `$value` to the `amount_sum_recursive` function. The result that will be returned is merged array, so we set this value back to `$result[$key]`

Comment: @MinaPandey Did my answer help you?